# joining tables to sum the amount of a items ordered

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

Have the following data tables:

```
menu_items:
item_id, 
item_name,
price,

sales: 
item_id,
customer_id,
employee_id,
date
```

I am attempting to join the tables on item_id. I want to display the item_name, number of item_names sold and date, and group them by the date. How should I adjust the code below to make the query work.

```
select item_name, count(item_name), date
from menu_items join sales
on item_id = item_id
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably found out, it won't work; all non-aggregated items must be contained in the `GROUP BY` clause. Also, you should use table aliases, always.

```
select s.date_col,
       i.item_name, 
       count(*) number_of_items_sold
from menu_items i join sales s on s.item_id = i.item_id
group by s.date_col, i.item_name
order by s.date_col, i.item_name;
```

If it is not what you wanted, please, post some sample data and desired output; it might be easier to answer, then.